# Meaning of "trade-off for stability"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does *trade-off for* within:

> Usage: The negative feedback also increases the input impedance of the amplifier as seen from the base, which can be advantageous. Due to the gain reduction from feedback, this biasing form is used only when the **trade-off for** stability is warranted.

mean the configuration is used only when stability is warranted?

Comment: The sentence doesn't make sense in the first place. What trade-off is being discussed? As a *standalone* sentence, it should be ***a***, not ***the***. Also, it's ambiguous if the trade-off is to *gain* stability or to *lose* stability. *Trade-off*, itself, simply means to exchange one thing for another. Here, only one thing is mentioned—and it's not clear if it's the thing that's coming or the thing that's going. The sentence says that it's the trade-off itself that's warranted. What that entails is unclear.

Comment: Is this about airplanes? I think we need more context

Comment: Here is the whole context as given in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_transistor_biasing#Types_of_bias_circuit_for_class-A_amplifiers#Usage) (see **Usage** section under **Fixed bias**)  article that describes the different ways in which a transistor can be connected: 

"Due to the gain reduction from feedback, this biasing form is used only when the trade-off for stability is warranted."

Comment: trade-off always means the same thing. There are not two meanings for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[trade-off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trade-off)** (n):
>   1 : a balancing of factors all of which are not attainable at the same time
>   2 : a giving up of one thing in return for another

The article says the biasing form "increases the input impedance", but also "reduces stability" (due to gain reduction from feedback).  So it's a *trade-off* between these two factors.  You can't have both, so you have to decide if it's OK -- if it's *warranted* -- for your application to be less stable.

There are many such trade-offs everywhere.  In civil engineering, for example, you can make a bridge more sturdy, but doing so makes it less flexible.  Or more expensive.  A computer application can be made *faster*, but only as a trade-off for *complexity*.

In everyday life, you can trade off having a larger house, farther away from the city, for having a longer commute to work.  Or buying a smaller house, as a trade-off for a lower mortgage payment.  And so on.